# Is it possible to display only section heading on the search page instated of all content in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, search, plugins

I am working on the WordPress search. I am using the below code to get the data on the search page.

```
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array(
                's' =>$s
            );
        
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 if( $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
    <ul>
 <? while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        $query->the_post(); 
       // print_r($query);
        
?>
<li><h2><a href='<?php echo the_permalink();?>'><?php echo the_title();?></a></h2></li>
<?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <?php

        };

?>
```

The above code is working. I am getting the title on the page.

Now, My concern is, Is it possible to get the specific content on the page?

I mean If I use `post_content` then I am getting all the content of the page. Is it possible to display only section heading on the search page?

Comment: WordPress content is an opaque blob unfortunately. However, you can pass that blob to something like DOMDocument and pull out the specific HTML tags that you are interested in.

Comment: Can you help me with example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Gutenberg?

You can actually loop through blocks by retrieving them from the content using `parse_blocks()`.

> Parses blocks out of a content string.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/

```
if ( ! empty( get_the_content() ) ) {

    $blocks = parse_blocks( get_the_content() );

    foreach ( $blocks as $block ) {

        if ( 'core/heading' === $block['blockName'] ) {

            echo wp_strip_all_tags( render_block( $block ) );

        };

    };

};
```

- see @ https://gist.github.com/MDSilviu/bb5d33bcc76c45be93c6f5fd8622d6f1 for a complete list of core blocks type.

Comment: I am using the wp bakery plugin for the page builder. Let me try your answer